# Heroku node.js app crashing right after deploy - running out of memory

Tags: node.js, heroku, memory

I'm new to heroku and dev ops. I have Node.js application and for deploying I'm using heroku hosting. Recently application started to crash right after deploy, with log messages:

```
2019-01-31T20:33:24.416498+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process running mem=851M(166.2%)
2019-01-31T20:33:24.416498+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)
2019-01-31T20:33:46.236152+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2019-01-31T20:33:46.053962+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process running mem=1033M(201.9%)
2019-01-31T20:33:46.054135+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R15 (Memory quota vastly exceeded)
2019-01-31T20:33:46.054135+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2019-01-31T20:33:46.215762+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
```

But after several hours, I was able to log into my application and it was working just fine. Situation repeated today with another deploy. In my app I'm using Express.js with express session. From express session I'm using memory store, which might cause memory leaks, but if I understand correctly: if crash would be cause by memory leak in my app, app would crashed when it was working. Here it crashes right after build. I checked my dependencies, locally my node_modules are taking about 144 Mb. What might be causing this problem.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Ps. I have no idea what kind of information might be useful (and I don't want to post my whole backend code)

Edit: After about 20 minutes:

```
2019-01-31T21:00:33.518851+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] Hash: c9a0035e314b6ab75f82
2019-01-31T21:00:33.518865+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] Version: webpack 4.25.1
2019-01-31T21:00:33.518866+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] Time: 122016ms
2019-01-31T21:00:33.518869+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] Built at: 01/31/2019 9:00:33 PM
```

Application is working fine. What might have caused those crashes right after deploy?

Edit2: Output of npm outdated:

```
autobind-decorator         2.3.1   2.3.1         2.4.0  
babel-loader               7.1.5   7.1.5         8.0.5  
clean-webpack-plugin       1.0.0   1.0.0         1.0.1  
css-loader                 1.0.1   1.0.1         2.1.0  
less                       3.8.1   3.8.1         3.9.0  
mini-css-extract-plugin    0.4.5   0.4.5         0.5.0  
mongodb                   3.1.10  3.1.10        3.1.13  
react                     16.6.3  16.6.3        16.7.0  
react-bootstrap           0.32.4  0.32.4  1.0.0-beta.5  
react-dom                 16.6.3  16.6.3        16.7.0  
react-icons                3.2.2   3.2.2         3.3.0  
react-perfect-scrollbar    1.4.2   1.4.4         1.4.4  
react-redux                5.1.1   5.1.1         6.0.0  
react-transition-group     2.5.2   2.5.3         2.5.3  
webpack                   4.25.1  4.25.1        4.29.0  
webpack-cli                3.1.2   3.1.2         3.2.1
```

Comment: Could you please paste the output of `npm outdated`?

Comment: Requested output added

Comment: OK, nothing memory-wise alarming here. Try running `process.memoryUsage();` locally on the server start, in some interval (20s) and watch for changes - does it go up to something round `851M` and then `1033M`, like on heroku?

If so, try [node-memwatch](https://github.com/lloyd/node-memwatch) to find out the leak locally.

Comment: Another thing, but this is a big leap - your assets might precompile on deploy via less&webpack - do you have a lot of them? If so, you can try turning the precompilation off and then check the deploy again.

Comment: Memory usage is quite constant - starts with 18Mb initially, then goes down to 13mb and stays at that point. I'm not using any assets (if you mean images, etc. by that). However yes, I'm using webpack (MiniCssExtractPlugin to be specific) to compile less files to single css file. Might that really be a source of issue?